# How to use this?

Tags: discord.py

```
from discord import Client, Intents, Embed
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext

bot = Client(intents=Intents.default())
slash = SlashCommand(bot)

@slash.slash(name="test")
async def test(ctx: SlashContext):
    embed = Embed(title="Embed Test")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run("discord_token")
```

i'm using discord_slash.
but it  error everytime

```
line 2, in <module>
    from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'
```

i installed discord-py-interactions

how to fix this ;(

Comment: Did you install `discord_slash` module?

Comment: Please read [ask] and consider changing your title to summarize your question.

Answer (score 1):

Discord.py has been deprecated due to the new update of v13
Discord developers are still working on the libraries, so hold on!

Answer (score 0):

Install [`discord-py-slash-command`](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/):

```
pip install discord-py-slash-command
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
pip3 install discord_slash
```